# HTC Desire: Recovery Mode just shows 'Broken Phone' symbol

Tags: htc-desire, cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

I'm trying to install the CyanogenMod on my HTC desire. I've temporarily routed it an downloaded the ClockworkMod Recovery and the CyanogenMod with the RomManager app. Everything seems fine.

However when I reboot the phone and go into the Revovery-Mode it just shows me a 'Broken-Phone' icon instead of the recovery options. The symbol it shows is a Phone with a red triangle on top of it. Anyone an idea what could be wrong?

Edit: I used the Vision+ to root. But it was only a temporary rooting-tool. The permanent root didn't work. The Unrevoke-method doesn't seem to work. It never recognizes the phone. HBoot-driver are installed (on Windows). It tells that HTC Sync should be installed. It's not installed in the PC. Do I need it to remove it on the Phone? And how I do that?

Thanks for any leads / tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know (and by no means am I an expert on rooting) the phone with the red triangle is the standard HTC recovery mode, not the Clockworkmod recovery. So my guess is that your rooting method is not working correctly.

So, what method are you using and is your desire branded / locked to a network?

When I rooted my desire a few weeks back, I struggled to get Clockworkmod installed - I was using the Unrevoked method. I ended up having to factory reset the device to be able to install it, which is always an option, but you will lose all your saved date (I'm having to replay all the Angry Birds levels).

Comment: I used the Vision+ thingy to root. But it was only a temporary rooting-tool. The permanet root didn't work. The Unrevoke-method didn't seem to work. (will retry it again) How do I do a factory reset? I don't care about the data.

Comment: Just found out about the S-ON / S-OFF stuff on HTC Desires. Probably need the S-OFF mode. Will try to get to that and then retry everything.

Comment: Found the reason why Unrevoked didn't work. The HBoot-driver didn't fully work on my Windows box. Ran the whole thing on Linux and everything worked. Thx for the tipp that the Symbol means that the default revovery mode was still installed.